# Perl cookbook — interpolating functions within strings

Tags: perl

I am reading a perl cookbook and see below and wondering why `\` is needed here?

I am thinking it should work without it (just like `${ somefunction() }`   but I do see that it doesn't work without `\`

```
$phrase = "I have ${\($n + 1)} guanacos.";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print \($n + 1)
```

will show you `SCALAR(0x24843d0)`, which denotes a *scalar reference*.

```
${\($n + 1)}
```

will *dereference* the scalar ref, turning it into a scalar.

The parentheses `()` are a bit tricky here. They are the list constructor, so one could think that a reference to a list would give an array reference. But that's not the case. In fact, `\(1, 2, 3)` will give you a list of three scalar references. Likewise, `\(1)` will be a list of one scalar reference.

This is explained in the [*Making References* part of perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).

> Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using
>   square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of
>   references!
>
> ```
> @list = (\$a, \@b, \%c);
> @list = \($a, @b, %c);      # same thing!
> ```

Using this ref/deref construct inside an interpolation is a trick to get Perl executed and more complex expressions evaluated inside of interpolation. Without it, there would be no way to get `$n + 1`.

But note that this is not the most readable code. It would be preferable to either break the string into pieces like this

```
my $phrase = "I have " . $n + 1 . " guanacos."; # or with single quotes ''
```

or to use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html).

```
my $phrase = sprintf "I have %d guanacos", $n + 1; # or with single quotes ''
```

Both of these are way more readable, do the same thing, and there is no measurable difference in how fast they are. Clean code should always be your primary objective. Being clever is nice sometimes, but usually you write code for humans first.

---

You should probably read [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: it is so odd.. I know reference but clearly I don't understand it fully .. thank you so much!!

Comment: @user3502374 please see my update. I've addressed what I believe has confused you.

Comment: @Zaid thanks for fixing the typo. I overwrote it accidentally, but fixed it myself afterwards. :)

Comment: No worries. Agree with your last sentence as well: being clever is nice sometimes, but being nice is usually cleverer :)

Comment: @Zaid a lot of the Perl community people use this kind of ref/deref scheme for their names on Twitter nowadays. I've tried finding a reference (pun fully intended) for why they do that, but it seems I'm not in on the joke. Do you know why? I think it would fit this question culturally.

Comment: I honestly have no clue

Comment: I wonder if the source of the confusion is the bash `${expression}` construct which looks identical but functions very differently.